# Using a variable in an awk Bourne shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sh

I'm trying to write a script that will read the country I type in and then display the people who are from that country. It works fine when I write the code with the country I want in, but when I try to use a variable nothing happens. I've been working on this for hours, so could someone please help me. This is what I have so far.

```
              echo Please choose a country
              echo
              read country


              awk -F: -v theCountry="$country" '

              BEGIN {

              recordCount = 0
              printf "\t\tPlayers from that country\n\n"
              print theCountry
              }

              /theCountry/{

              print $1
              recordCount++


              }

              END {


              }' playerFile
```

Where I enter theCountry is where it's messing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
/theCountry/{
```

to:

```
$0 ~ theCountry {
```

and read http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps

Comment: Thank you so much. I am forever in your debt. Thank you for that site, too!

Comment: You're welcome. Just click on the "Accepted" check mark next to my answer and we'll call it even ;-).

Comment: @EdMorton Users with reputation 1 can not accept answer.  They can mark it as useful. But the can come back later when reputation is higher to accept answer :)

Comment: @Jotne any user can accept an answer. What users with <15 rep cannot do is to upvote. See [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).